# Quicker alternatives to apply function when performing row wise computations on a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, function, performance, apply

I have a data frame with 10,000 rows and 40 columns. I am trying to apply a function to each of these rows. For each row, I am expecting to return a scalar which is the value of the statistic I am calculating in this function. Below is what I have done so far;

```
library(sandwich)

# Creating example data #

nrows=10000
ncols=40
n1=20
n2=20
df=data.frame(t(replicate(nrows, rnorm(ncols, 100, 3))))
cov=data.frame(group=as.factor(rep(c(1,2),c(n1,n2))))

# Function to evaluate on each row of df #

get_est= function(x){
mod = lm(x~cov$group)
vcov = vcovHC(mod)
coef = as.numeric(mod$coefficients[2])
se = sqrt(as.numeric(diag(vcov)[2]))
stats = coef/se
return(stats)
}

# Applying above function to full data #

t1=Sys.time()
estimates=apply(df, 1, function(x) get_est(x))
t2=Sys.time()-t1

# Time taken by apply function

Time difference of 32.10623 secs
```

Is there a way to significantly decrease the time taken to implement get_est() on the full data?
The main reason I need to speed up the computation on a single df is because I have 1000 more data frames with the same dimension and I have to apply this function to each row to each of these data frames simultaneously. To illustrate, below is the broader situation I am dealing with;

```
# Creating example data

set.seed(1234)
nrows = 10000
ncols = 40
n1 = 20
n2 = 20
df.list = list()
for(i in 1:1000){
  df.list[[i]] = data.frame(t(replicate(nrows, rnorm(ncols, 100, 3))))
}

# Applying get_est() to each row and to each of data frame in df.list #

all.est = foreach(j = 1:length(df.list), .combine = cbind, .packages = 'sandwich') %dopar% {
  cov=data.frame(group=as.factor(rep(c(1,2),c(n1,n2))))
  est = apply(df.list[[j]], 1, function(x) get_est(x))
  return(est)
}
```

Even after parallelizing it is taking hours to finish. My ultimate objective is to significantly cut down the time to obtain "all.est" which will contain 10000 rows and 1000 columns where each column has the stats estimates for the respective data set. Any help is much appreciated!! Thanks in advance!

Comment: not strictly on topic but maybe using `lapply/parlapply` (or similar) instead of the for loop can squeeze out a few seconds overall.

Comment: @D.J yes, apply family can be used to avoid the loop. However, in reality I do possess these 1000 data sets so, in my actual code I do not run this for loop. It was just to create the example data sets for illustration in here. My main concern is speeding up the computation of "all.est" given these 1000 data sets.

Answer (score 0):

It get halved in my computer.

```
library(snowfall)
t1=Sys.time()
sfInit( parallel=TRUE, cpus=2 )

sfExport(list=list('get_est'))
sfLibrary('sandwich', character.only = TRUE)
sfExport('df')
sfExport('cov')


## call function using sfApply; will return values as a list object
out = sfApply(df, 1, function(x) get_est(x))

## stop parallel computing job
sfStop()
Sys.time()-t1

Time difference of 15.29727 secs
```

Comment: thanks, sfapply does cut it down to half for a single data frame however, when I implement it inside the foreach loop to calculate "all.est" my computer froze. Maybe sfapply is conflicting with foreach?

Comment: @Capri maybe your computer's CPU have 1 or 2 cores.

Comment: no, I just checked it has 12 cores. Did you try implementing sfApply inside the foreach to calculate "all.est"? Did it work?

Comment: @Capri Oh, I'm sorry. I was confusing `all.est` and `get_est`.  My computer froze too. I'll look up to `all.est`. i'm sorry.

Comment: No worries. Thanks for your help!!